# Docker runs fine but commands crashes with error

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm not a pro in Docker for Windows but have been using it for few months and everything was fine.

My setup:
Windows 10 Pro x64
Docker for Windows version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

One day after my system rebooted I've got this error for every docker command (with about 40 seconds delay for response):

> error during connect: Get
>   http://192.168.99.100:2375/v1.35/images/json: dial tcp
>   192.168.99.100:2375: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
>   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.

Virtualization is enabled, Hyper-V is seems to running fine. I have reinstalled Docker few times, removed Hyper-V adapters as well - same result.
Docker shows no errors during the installation, starting and running.

Seems like the only Docker command that runs normally is `docker --version`, but it takes about 10 seconds as well.

Comment: Firewall? But the ten seconds is short for a time out.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I'm in corporate network and my collegues have same machines with the same configs and their Dockers keep working fine.

Comment: Measured timeout for `docker image ls` response - 40 seconds

Comment: But your system rebooted. Your colleagues'?

Comment: Just asking because there have been windows updates for Spectre & Meltdown that made life difficult for virtual hosting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure their machines are in the same state (Windows build, applied updates etc.)

Comment: On linux, docker has /var/log/docker.log.  Any trace of logging on your system?  BTW, I hope you agree there is a difference between your system and that of your colleagues.  You're sure one of them rebooted and is still doing fine?

Comment: Sure! general windows configs are identical, their machines are rebooting permanently as well. I'm nut sure it's the root of the problem. I found Docker's log.txt and here's the output for the last crashed command: `[15:42:56.400][LocalhostForwarder][Info   ] Reconciliation succeeded
[15:42:56.401][WindowsDaemon  ][Info   ] debug: Calling GET /v1.34/containers/json?limit=0`

Comment: Something's changed since the OP?  v1.35 to v1.34 ?  If you're mixing versions, do you recognize this: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1546 ?  I must say, the log is incredibly short, has it been rotated?

Comment: Nothing's changed. There's really only 2 lines of logs per 1 command execution. Docker startup logs were omitted. `docker version` returns only Client version (API v1.35) and same error. I always work with Linux containers and never switched to Windows

Comment: Start "strace docker --version" just to find out why he needs 10 seconds for that.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](http://oi63.tinypic.com/10eefxi.jpg).

Comment: I'm trying to get that image, but the company firewall doesn't like that one bit (let alone byte).

Comment: Can you have another go with strace, this time "strace -f -o /tmp/docker.trc -tt docker --version".  Then upload /tmp/docker.trc, which is a text file that should tell us what's happening during the delay.  "-f" follows child processes.  "-tt" so that you don't have to indicate where the delay is ;-)

Comment: thanks for the tip) here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yIJWy8ZB_AUJUyJktPp8XcapBn8SQ90Z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That wasn't a trace created with the "-f" and "-tt".  It corresponds to your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was in the environment variables. I checked them and there was DOCKER_HOST pointing to 192.168.99.100, after deleting it everything's working fine. Where it comes from is still a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

The problems was: I used to have Docker Toolbox on my PC before. So, I had Environmental Variables:

DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY,

DOCKER_CERT_PATH,

DOCKER_HOST,

DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH.

I deleted them and it helped.